# Multidimensional array sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How can i sort "award_year" whereby all the other key will follow the sort order. All key names except "award_year" will vary in name as well as total keys as well?

```
    array(7) {
      ["award_year"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "1999-01"
        [1]=>
        string(7) "2010-02"
      }
      ["award_title_user"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "2"
        [1]=>
        string(2) "tt"
      }
      ["award_description_user"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "2"
        [1]=>
        string(3) "ddd"
      }
      ["award_title_lang1"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "ms"
        [1]=>
        string(3) "ms2"
      }
      ["award_description_lang1"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "ms"
        [1]=>
        string(3) "ms2"
      }
    }
```

Please advice.

Comment: ,I have posted answer of your question.Please check it & let me know if you still have any issues !

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the fastest way but:

```
sort($arrayin['award_year']);
$arrayout = array();
foreach( $arrayin["award_year"] as $key => $value ){
  array_push($arrayout['award_year'], $array_in['award_year'][$key]);
  array_push($arrayout['award_title_user'], $array_in['award_title_user'][$key]);
  //etc
}
```

Comment: This is not good way.If array contains more than thousand elements then It's load very slow. And also If PHP gives function for doing same then no need to do it with manually. Hope you can understand scenario.

Comment: I was using this: array_multisort($awards['award_year'], SORT_DESC, $awards['award_title_user'], $awards['award_description_user']); but then since i dont know the key names or total amount, i cant use this now.

Answer (score 0):

for PHP 5.3:

```
//Sample Multi-dimensional Array ($myArray)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [award_year]       => 2012
            [award_title_user] => test2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [award_year]       => 2011
            [award_title_user] => test1
        )

)

usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['award_year'] - $b['award_year'];
});

print_r($myArray);
```

Comment: All the keys has been removed using this method

Comment: @AnilAstrio, Which PHP version you're using ? Also can you please provide your actual array ?

Comment: I have implemented it's working fine at my end ! Also I have edited my answer & put code same as I have implemented locally.

Comment: I am using Php 5.4.32 and the above is the actual array. Let me do a few more test

Comment: But the i will then lose the key e.g. [award_year][0]=>"1999-01"[1]=>"2010-02". This works for me : array_multisort($awards['award_year'], SORT_DESC, $awards['award_title_user'], $awards['award_description_user']); but how can i add all the keys in this array_multisort function. Any idea?

Comment: @AnilAstrio,You can change your array structure similar to my-array (i.e I have created) & then use usort.It should work fine! 
So In Each sub-array you've keys [award_year] [award_title_user][award_description_user] & so on.. Got My Point ? Or still you've confusion ?

Comment: Sorry just started web coding 2 months ago. Still confused. $awards = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'awards', true);, which produces the top array. Using your code i get an "Undefined index: award_year" i am still trying to figure this out

Comment: @AnilAstrio,Can you print your full array & gives me so I can resolve your issue !

Comment: Thanks: This is directly from php admin:    a:7:{s:10:"award_year";a:2:{i:0;s:7:"1999-01";i:1;s:7:"2010-02";}s:16:"award_title_user";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:2:"tt";}s:22:"award_description_user";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:3:"ddd";}s:14:"award_title_ms";a:2:{i:0;s:2:"ms";i:1;s:3:"ms2";}s:20:"award_description_ms";a:2:{i:0;s:2:"ms";i:1;s:3:"ms2";}s:19:"award_title_zh_Hans";a:2:{i:0;s:3:"2CC";i:1;s:2:"zz";}s:25:"award_description_zh_Hans";a:2:{i:0;s:8:"2CCCCCCC";i:1;s:3:"dzz";}}

Comment: FROM print_r: Array ( [award_year] => Array ( [0] => 1999-01 [1] => 2010-02 ) [award_title_user] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => tt ) [award_description_user] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => ddd ) [award_title_ms] => Array ( [0] => ms [1] => ms2 ) [award_description_ms] => Array ( [0] => ms [1] => ms2 ) [award_title_zh_Hans] => Array ( [0] => 2CC [1] => zz ) [award_description_zh_Hans] => Array ( [0] => 2CCCCCCC [1] => dzz ) )